# Changing the_posts_navigation() html output

Tags: php, loop

I'm using underscores which uses the_posts_navigation(); in the archive.

Any way to change this language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function use the [`get_the_posts_navigation()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_navigation/) to change the text **Older posts** and **Newer posts** you can pass array with the args.

See this example with the default values:

```
the_posts_navigation(
    array(
        'prev_text' => __('Older posts', 'theme_textdomain'),
        'next_text' => __('Newer posts', 'theme_textdomain'),
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'theme_textdomain')
    )
);
```